# Class not found PHP Code Sniffer

Tags: php, class

I am using PHP_CodeSniffer to clean my project code.

But below error occurred while validating a class file.
I got the latest version 2.3.4 PHP_CodeSniffer [here](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/download).

I am using windows machine with the below command.

### Command : C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_CodeSniffer-2.3.4\PHP_CodeSniffer-2.3.4\scripts\phpcs C:\xampp\htdocs\rat\class\modules.class.php

```
Error : "Class Generic_Sniffs_Functions_OpeningFunctionBraceBsdAllmanSniff not found"
```

[image]

How to resolve this.

Comment: maybe some code, explanation of what are you using, how did you get there..

Comment: @XicoXpertoI have edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this issue.

The class file was missed on the path

```
"C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_CodeSniffer-2.3.4\PHP_CodeSniffer-2.3.4\CodeSniffer\Standards\Generic\Sniffs\Functions"
```

I placed the [class](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/CodeSniffer/Standards/Generic/Sniffs/Functions/OpeningFunctionBraceBsdAllmanSniff.php) with the file name `"OpeningFunctionBraceBsdAllmanSniff.php"` at the same path.

Now I can use the PHP Code Sniffer to validate my files.